# Convert Generic Types to Objects

Tags: java, generics, transform, factory

I am writing a transformer to convert `String` input to output of custom type. Here's how the `interface` looks like:

```
public interface Transformer<T> {
    public T transform(String input);
}
```

There will multiple implementations of it (i.e. `IntegerTransformer`, `ByteTransformer` etc). I have written a factory that returns these transformers, e.g.:

```
public class TransformerFactory {
    public <T> Transformer<T> getTransformer(final SomeEnum enum, final T type) {
        switch(enum) {
        case FOO:
            return new IntegerTransformer();
        case BAR:
            return new ByteTransformer();
            default:
                throw new Exception("blah");
        }
    }
}
```

In my `main` class, I am doing this:

```
factory.getTransformer(foo, Integer.class).transform(input);
```

This results in the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Integer> to Integer
```

So, I somehow need to convert `Type` literal to `Object`. Is there any way I can do that without modifying the generic structure of interface and factory?

Comment: Since you don't use `type` parameter, why do you need it?

Comment: The parameter should be `Class<T> type` instead. That's what `Integer.class` is: a `Class<Integer>`.

Comment: @MAnouti that was it, if you can post it as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: You can't do this with generics: you can invoke `getTransformer(SomeEnum.FOO, Integer.valueOf(0))` and `getTransformer(SomeEnum.FOO, Byte.valueOf(0))` - and both cannot be type-correct. The best you can do is to return a `Transformer<?>` from the method.

Comment: @Steyrix this is just an illustrative example. I do use the type in the actual implementation

Comment: „*...this is just an illustrative example*...“ — Even so, Darshan Mehta, the code as it's posted in your question [*produces an error that is different*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307436) from the one in your question. Unnecessary details that don't contribute to the problem you're reporting only makes providing a satisfactory solution to your problem, less likely. It also makes your problem statement less clear/more confusing. Same deal with missing or incomplete details. Being able to reproduce the same error you report is crucial. Otherwise, people might investigate down the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***TL;DR***: Not trying to snipe @MAnouti's points that you've earmarked for him/her. But for the sake of completeness, OP, I wanted to share what I observed in [*my attempt to reproduce your error*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307436).

---

> „*This results in the following error:*“
>
> ```
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Integer> to Integer
> ```

The original example code in your question fails to compile ([*as confirmed by my failed attempt to reproduce the same error*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307436)) with these *different* compilation errors…

```
...
incompatible types: IntegerTransformer cannot be converted to Transformer<T>
...
incompatible types: ByteTransformer cannot be converted to Transformer<T>
...
```

…Notice those are not the same as the error you reported in your question.

And even if you did follow the advice of the other answers/comments and replaced *`T`* with *`Class<T>`* as the second formal parameter of your method, you would still get the above *`cannot be converted to Transformer<T>`* compilation errors.

> „*…Is there any way I can do that without modifying the generic structure of interface and factory?*“

I have [*confirmed by a simple experiment*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307438) that this meets that criteria. ***And*** it successfully compiles and runs as expected…

```
    public < T, U extends Transformer< T > > U getTransformer( SomeEnum eNum, Class< T > type ){ 
    
    switch( eNum ){ 
        case FOO:
            return (U)new IntegerTransformer( );
        case BAR:
            return (U)new ByteTransformer( );
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException( "Detected Decepticons Among Us!" );
    }
}
```

…It fixes both the error you reported in your question, ***and*** the *`cannot be converted to Transformer<T>`* errors you'd get if the only thing you changed was the parameter to *`Class<T>`*.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was getting `cannot be converted to Transformer<T>` error and was trying the workarounds like using of wildcard, `extends` keyword but neither worked. With the above solution, I am able to both write and execute the code. Thanks for the comprehensive answer, I think this is more complete than @MAnouti's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `getTransformer(final SomeEnum enum, final T type)` expects an actual objet of type `T`. What you want is pass a instance of `class`, so it should be:
`getTransformer(final SomeEnum enum, final Class<T> type)`

In addition, since Java 8 there is no need for declaring such simple interfaces. Using the generic `Function<String,T>` would serve you perfectly.

Comment: So, what's the type of `getTransformer(SomeEnum.FOO, Integer.class)`, and what's the type of `getTransformer(SomeEnum.FOO, Byte.class)`?